# Spark RDD loaded into LevelDB via toLocalIterator creates corrupted database

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, leveldb

I have a Spark computation that I want to persist into a simple leveldb database - once all the heavy lifting is done by Spark (in Scala here).

So my code goes like this :

```
private def saveRddToLevelDb(rdd: RDD[(String, Int)], target: File) = {
    import resource._

    val options = new Options()
    options.createIfMissing(true)
    options.compressionType(CompressionType.SNAPPY)

    for (db <- managed(factory.open(target, options))) { // scala-arm
        rdd.map { case (key, score) =>
            (bytes(key), bytes(score.toString))
        }.toLocalIterator.foreach { case (key, value) =>
            db.put(key, value)
        }
    }
}
```

And all is right with the world. But then if I try to open the created database and do a **get** on it :

```
org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB$DBException: IO error: .../leveldb-data/000081.sst: Invalid argument
    org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.get(NativeDB.java:316)
    org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.get(NativeDB.java:300)
    org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.get(NativeDB.java:293)
    org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.JniDB.get(JniDB.java:85)
    org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.JniDB.get(JniDB.java:77)
```

I managed however to make it by, not simply opening the created leveldb database, but repairing it beforehand... (in java this time) :

```
factory.repair(new File(levelDbDirectory, "leveldb-data"), options);
DB db = factory.open(new File(levelDbDirectory, "leveldb-data"), options);
```

So, everything's all right then ?! 
Yes, but my only question is **why ?**
What am I doing wrong when I **put** all my data into leveldb :

- the open-stream to the database is managed by scala-arm, therefore closed properly afterwards
- My JVM is not killed or anything
- There's only one process, heck even only one thread - the driver one, accessing the database (via the **toLocalIterator** method)
- and finally, if I open the database using the paranoid mode, leveldb doesn't care before I try to **get** on it. So the database is not exactly corrupted in its eyes.

I've read about the fact that the **put** write is actually async, I did not however try to change the **WriteOptions** to synced, but wouldn't the **close** method wait for the process to flush everything ?